# Shiny: How to reference a value from a temporary table?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to reference a specific value(s) from a temporary table that is generated in an R Shiny app.

The idea is that a user would create inputs through prompts, the inputs would serve as filters for a larger dataframe, and the filtered results would then be displayed as a table.

Once a filtered table is shown, I would like to reference a specific column in this temporary table and print/render the value(s).

My current attempt shows the values from the specified column, but as it is referencing the full dataframe (dfIris), all of the values are being printed rather than just the ones shown in the temporary table.

In the example shown below (setosa / 5.3), I would only expect to see "0.20" displayed in the "Matching Petal Width" box:

[image: Example:]

I've attempted to use 'requestedData', 'flowerFilter', and 'flowerTable' without success.
Here is a sample of a reproducible Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dfIris <- iris

########
#  UI  #
########

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Copy the line below to make a select box 
  selectInput("species_value", label = h3("Select Species"), 
              choices = list("setosa" = "setosa", "versicolor" = "versicolor", "virginica" = "virginica"), 
              selected = 1),

  selectInput("sepal_length", "Select Sepal Length", choices = NULL),

  fluidRow(column(width = 8, box(title = "Matching Flowers", width = NULL, status = "primary",
                                 div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll', tableOutput("flowerTable"))))),
  br(),
  br(),
  fluidRow(column(width = 4, box(title = "Matching Petal Width", width = NULL, status = "primary",
                                verbatimTextOutput("width"))))
  )

############
#  Server  #
############

server <- shinyServer(function(session,input, output) {

  observe({
    print(input$species_value)
    validLengths <- dfIris$Sepal.Length[dfIris$Species == input$species_value]
    updateSelectInput(session, "sepal_length", "Select Sepal Length", choices = unique(validLengths))
  })  

  requestedData <- reactive(subset(dfIris, dfIris$Species == input$species_value
                                  & dfIris$Sepal.Length == input$sepal_length))


  # Generate a table with matching Flowers ----
  output$flowerTable <- renderTable({
    flowerFilter <- subset(dfIris, dfIris$Species == input$species_value
                             & dfIris$Sepal.Length == input$sepal_length)}, 
    striped = TRUE , bordered = TRUE, hover = TRUE, align = 'c')

  output$width <- renderPrint({ dfIris$Petal.Width})
})


###############
#  Shiny App  #
###############

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to make the `flowerFilter` object available to `output$width` WITHIN the expression and filter your output:

```
output$width <- renderPrint({ 
    ## recreate filtered table
    flowerFilter <- subset(dfIris, dfIris$Species == input$species_value
                           & dfIris$Sepal.Length == input$sepal_length)
    ## filter output based on what's in the filtered table
    dfIris$Petal.Width[dfIris$Petal.Width %in% flowerFilter$Petal.Width]

    })
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This indeed looks to be the way to go.  One clarifying question, in the example shown above, I would have expected a single return of "0.2" as there is only one row returned after filtering.  

With your answer applied, I receive the following output:   

`[1] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2`

Do you know why this is?  How would I get it to just return the single matching value (rather than have it repeated)?

Comment: 29 flowers have that petal.width. So, if the second data frame is only filtered on petal.width, you'll get 29 data points.  Should the second data frame be filtered more?  Otherwise, you can wrap the output in `unique()` to get a single value.

Comment: That makes sense.  I added the prior filter `validLengths <- dfIris$Sepal.Length[dfIris$Species == input$species_value]` to this expression and now it returns the single `0.2`, as expected.  I'll be sure to also wrap with `unique()` for those instances in which more than one row is returned.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Happy to help you out!